# How do I pull a value from an appended element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Right now I have a Faq area on my website that I wanted to add an 'edit' field to for each question/answer.

I added a modal overlay that uses the .text(); function to populate the 'question' and 'answer' fields with what was there before, rather than having to query the server again. (So the modal overlay is the area where we would edit the question.) This works correctly for all items on the page.

I have a second function that uses the .append() feature along with Ajax to insert a new question/answer into the database and then dynamically add it to the page. This also works correctly.

My problem is that on the newest item I've just appended to the page (since append() only changes the DOM and not the actual source) I can't use the .text(); function to pull up a modal populated with the information from the appended element, since it doesn't technically exist in the source. So my edit field is blank where the question and answer goes, instead of containing the user's previous entry.

Is there a way to use .text() to find an appended element, or a way to use an analogous feature to populated the question and answer fields without querying the database?

(The entire point of javascript/jquery here was to use the elements on the page that have already loaded (i.e. the old questions and answers) to populate the new 'edit' fields, rather than having to query the database again for the question & answer to edit.)

Comment: _“I can't use the .text(); function to pull up a modal populated with the information from the appended element, since it doesn't technically exist in the source”_ – that’s just wrong – `.text` does not look at the “source code”, it gets the text of the selected elements from the DOM as well (JavaScript does not even have access to the “source code” of a page in the browser per se). Whatever your problem is, it must be something else – what we can’t say, because you have not provided any useful information about what your code is actually doing.

Comment: can you provide the html of the appended element and the ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can delegate a binding to the document which will listen to events to a selector even if its not there, so youre .text example could be sth like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.notYetExisting',function(){
       alert('trigerred a click!'+$(this).text());
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').append('<span class="notYetExisting">baarfooo</span>');
    },1000);
});
```

so you see the binding was made when there was no element with class "notYetExisting" but it will alert as soon as its there and you click on it ( in this example its appended a second later )

so it would be the same with you ajax stuff